# Cassandra not coming up after installing dse-full

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax

I had a working 3 node cassandra cluster and I found that during the installation i didn't install dse. So I installed dse-full & opscenter in all of the three nodes. But after the installation I found that none of the cassandra node was up so I rebooted the cluster nodes. After the reboot when I tried to run caassandra service I faced following exception:

```
Fatal exception during initialization
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Saved cluster name DB Cluster != configured name Test Cluster                                                                                                            
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.SystemKeyspace.checkHealth(SystemKeyspace.java:542)                                                                                                                   
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:246)                                                                                                                     
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.setup(DseDaemon.java:376)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:480)                                                                                                                     
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.main(DseDaemon.java:639)
```

After reading few of the posts I changed the cluster name to 'Test Cluster' in cassandra.yaml in each of the nodes and then tried to run cassandra service but cassandra is not coming up and nothing is logging in the system.log/output.log.
Any help as I don't want to lose my data.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you to change all of the Cluster Names to "DB Cluster". So do that in all the yaml files and you should be ok. (Also make sure to fix any other yaml changes - seed nodes, data directories, listen addresses, ect ... )

Comment: No, originally the name of the cluster was "DB Cluster" and when I rebooted the system and tried to start the node I got this error. And then I changed the cluster name to "Test Cluster" as I mentioned the cassandra didn't start but I didn't see any error.

Comment: Saved cluster name DB Cluster != configured name Test Cluster - Means that C* has within its saved data knowledge that it is part of a cluster "DB Cluster". Configured name Test Cluster means that the yaml file is specifying the DB Name as "Test Cluster". If you have old data with "DB Cluster" You need to have the cluster name as DB Cluster. If you happened to start up another node completely into it's own cluster and it wasn't able to join you'll need to wipe that node's data directory and rename it so it can join the correct cluster.

Comment: Okey but I did it that way also but none of the node is coming up. 
When I do..."service cassandra start" and look at the system.log or output.log nothing comes there and "ps -ef| grep cassandra" doesn't show anything.
Is there any other way to debug the cause.